# Symbol.for(string) in ECMAScript 6

Tags: javascript, symbols, ecmascript-6

It took me a while but I finally figured out what the purpose of symbols in ECMAScript 6 is: avoiding name collision when attaching properties to shared objects - HTML elements e.g. (In case you're stuck on the same question, I recommend [this article](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/06/es6-in-depth-symbols/).)

But then I stumbled upon [Symbol.for()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/for). Apparently ECMAScript 6 will maintain a global symbol registry which you can query with this function by providing the symbol description. Come again? If I use symbols to avoid name collisions, why would I want code other than my own to use them? (*) And how would I avoid name collisions in that global registry? Sharing of symbols seems to completely subvert the concept and a global registry doubly so.

(*) Yes, I know symbols aren't *truly* private, but that's besides the point.

Comment: Since it's unclear from your question, doing `Symbol('some description');` does not register things in the global registry. It's only if you explicitly ask for a globally registered symbol via `Symbol.for`.

Comment: Here your concern is answered by the author: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/06/es6-in-depth-symbols/comment-page-1/#comment-17848

Comment: That's not much of an example though. Simply stating that code may have the need to access properties across libraries and/or iframes doesn't illustrate why a symbol registry is the answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you don't want your symbols to be available in GlobalSymbolRegistry, just don't use `Symbol.for`.

Only use it if you want to allow other codes to use your symbol.

In the following example, I create a symbol to store data in DOM elements. And I may want every other code (e.g. [internal raw uncompiled handlers](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#internal-raw-uncompiled-handler)) to read that data. So I make the symbol globally available.

```js
var sym = Symbol.for('storeDataInDOM');
document.querySelector('button')[sym] = 'Hello, world!';
```

```html
<button onclick="alert(this[Symbol.for('storeDataInDOM')])">Click me</button>
```

It's like creating global variables: should be avoided in general, but has its advantages. But with symbols instead of strings.

Comment: The question is rather: Why would I want to share my symbols?

Comment: @PeterCoester I added an example. But the question is: why not? ES6 provides a way to do so, use it if you are interested, or ignore it otherwise.

Comment: But doesn't sharing of symbols create the very same problem symbols were created to solve? Your example doesn't exactly show a use case for sharing symbols.

Comment: @PeterCoester Yes, there is a risk of collision. But global variables have the same problem and people use them anyways. And in my example: how would you access a symbol in an internal raw uncompiled handler? Introducing a GlobalSymbolRegistry allows to do so without polluting the global object.

Comment: Hm. Yes, I think I can see a bunch of use cases now... Symbols could be used like the [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) function in jQuery and you could attach and manipulate UI controls this way e.g.


Thanks! That helped. I've upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 6):

> If I use symbols to avoid name collisions, why would I want code other than my own to use them?

That's not the only use case of symbols. The two most important other ones are:

- they don't collide with string-keyed properties
- they are not enumerated by the usual mechanics

> Sharing of symbols seems to completely subvert the concept and a global registry doubly so.

Not necessarily. Right from [that article](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/06/es6-in-depth-symbols/) you read: "*The registry is useful when multiple web pages, or multiple modules within the same web page, need to share a symbol.*" The best example for these are the intrinsic symbols - they guarantee **interoperability** across realms, that's why the [global symbol registry](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31897015/1048572) is more global than your global scope.

For example you might have a library that is loaded in a web page, an iframe and a web worker. If you share data between those environments (realms), all of the three instances of your library would want to use the *same* symbol.

There also is a real need interoperability between different libraries, which might not even know about each other. Good examples are [transducers](https://github.com/cognitect-labs/transducers-js#transformer-protocol), [algebraic structures](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land/issues/92) or [promises](http://promisesaplus.com/). Would ES6 already be in use, all of these would have agreed on common names in the global symbol registry, instead of relying on strings like [these](https://github.com/queckezz/transducer-protocol/blob/f60ff1a9f742f2bf90e91466301a050a49fca7f1/index.js) or the `then` method.

[Another good example](http://blog.keithcirkel.co.uk/metaprogramming-in-es6-symbols/#3givingdevelopersabilitytoaddhookstotheirobjectsthroughyourapi) would be custom hooks defined by your engine, e.g. a `Symbol.inspect = Symbol.for("inspect")` that you can use to define custom stringification behavior to be used by `console.log`. Admittedly, that symbol does not necessarily need to be made available through the global symbol registry, it could as well be put on that specific library object (e.g. `console.inspect = Symbole("console.inspect")`).

> And how would I avoid name collisions in that global registry?

Just like you previously did with properties, or global module objects: by using very long, very descriptive names - or by good faith. Also there are [some naming conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31362186/1048572).

Answer (score 0):

I invented the most useful feature of `Symbol.for()` call. If there is using symbols in your code sometimes it is difficult to use *conditional breakpoints* while debugging. For example, you need to catch if the variable equals the value which is of symbol type and this value binded in the different module. The first difficult way is to use this value as a constant and export it from that module. In this case, the condition of the breakpoint will look:

```
catchedVariable === exportedSymbolConst
```

But the easiest way is to temporarily change the code inside the module adding `.for` to `Symbol`. Then you can write the condition:

```
catchedVariable === Symbol.for('string_key')
```

After the successful debugging you will be changing the code back just removing `.for` part.