# Is there a convention for naming symbols in ES6?

Tags: javascript, symbols, ecmascript-6

I'm toying around with ES6, looking at symbols. Unlike ruby for example where you'd write `:symbol`, ES6 symbols seem to be allowed any "standard" variable name. To be honest I am finding this rather confusing:

```
var privateProperty = Symbol();
var obj = {};
obj[privateProperty] = 'some value goes here';
```

as it tends to make me think that `privateProperty` is probably a plain string like the years before. Using `:privateProperty` is not valid.

So just like using `$bar` for a jQuery object or `bar$` for a RxJS/Bacon stream, I was wondering if there is already an established convention for naming symbols in ES6?

Comment: A symbol is just a value. The variable you assign it to is not its name. The variable is just a container for the value, just like for any other value (number, string, object, ...).

Comment: I am aware of that, my example is just misleading, editing.

Comment: Changing the variable name doesn't really make any difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> `obj[privateProperty] = …;` tends to make me think that `privateProperty` is probably a plain string like the years before.

Well, that's the old thinking that we will need to forget. `privateProperty` is a ***key***, which can be either a string (property *name*) or symbol. Similarly, we already have learned to distinguish (integer) *indices* from "normal" properties.

> ES6 seems to allow any "standard" variable name

Just as does Ruby. The difference is that ES6 doesn't introduce a literal notation for symbols (which resolve to the same thing), but allows them to be created only by using `Symbol` (locally) or `Symbol.for` (globally).

There is **no standard convention** for naming variables that hold symbol values.
Of course, you can always use [hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) if you tend to want such type annotations. If I had to coin a standard, I'd propose to use a more subtle leading underscore (`var _myPrivate`). Underscores in property names had always implied something special, and it would look similar for computed property keys (`obj[_myPrivate]`) then.

> Is there a convention for naming symbols in ES6?

While there is no convention for naming symbol-holding variables (yet), there certainly is a convention for naming symbols themselves:

- local symbols should have a very descriptive descriptor string (given as an argument to `Symbol`). Of course, they're still unique anyway, so you basically can use whatever name you want.
- global symbols need to avoid collisions. The convention is to namespace them appropriately, and connect those namespace names with dots - like a Java package name. If the symbol is available as a global variable, its descriptor should have the same name (similar to the builtin, native symbols, which are like `@@iterator = Symbol.for("Symbol.iterator");`). If the symbol is exported by a module or library, its descriptor should be prefixed with the module/library name (to avoid collisions).

And it would probably be a best practise to use the same name for the variable (like the native symbols already do, `Symbol.iterator.toString() == "Symbol(Symbol.iterator)"`).

Comment: What is about variables that hold references to Symbols? Sometimes I store them in objects but sometimes in distinct variables as well. There can be name collisions in my own code, when a function would have to have the same name. I tend to write those vars in upper case: `const MAP = Symbol("map")` but am not sure. Oh, and Symbols are immutable.

Comment: @IvenMarquardt As I said, there is no convention for those either. Using uppercase names in your case is probably more because it's a constant, less because it holds a symbol.