# Difference between Symbol() and Symbol.for()

Tags: ecmascript-6

I try to create object with `Symbol` key and find corresponding value with `Symbol.for`, but it doesn't work:

```
const sym = Symbol("x");

let obj = {
  [sym]: "val"
}

console.log(obj[sym]); // "val"
console.log(obj[Symbol.for("x")]); // undefined, but expected "val"
```

Why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Symbol.for(string) in ECMAScript 6](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30984858/1048572). Notice also that `Symbol("x") !== Symbol("x")`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Symbols created using `Symbol()` are unique and immutable, so the only way you can reference it is by assigning it to a variable.

It's important to note that the constructor param is actually a *description* of the symbol, *not a key*. From MDN:

> A description of the symbol which can be used for debugging **but not to
>   access the symbol itself**

<sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

`Symbol.for` on the other hand stores Symbols in a global registry list using the specified *key*, so for your example to work you need to both create *and* access the symbol using `Symbol.for`:

```
const sym = Symbol.for("x"); // Create a symbol in the global registry

let obj = {
  [sym]: "val"
}

console.log(obj[Symbol.for("x")]); // Access the symbol from the global registry
```

Comment: From the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/for): _“**In contrast to `Symbol()`, the `Symbol.for()` function creates a symbol available in a global symbol registry list.** `Symbol.for()` does also not necessarily create a new symbol on every call, but checks first if a symbol with the given key is already present in the registry.”_ So `Symbol()` doesn’t add a symbol to any global registry, only `Symbol.for()` does. (Just as a clarification.)

Comment: @Xufox Thanks, that's a good clarification as I couldn't quite get my terminology for `Symbol()` across the way I wanted

Comment: So `Symbol("x")` and `Symbol.for("x")` absolutely different symbols?

Comment: Yes. They are always different symbols.

Comment: @RGraham @Xufox, thus `Symbol.for` is not so *isolate*? For example, if I will use `Symbol.for("very-unique")`, and another developer library will use the same, there will be incorrect behavior? If it's true, what are the benefits from it? Why not just a property with `["very-unique"]` name?

Comment: @mqklin Correct that it's not isolated, but take for example `var obj = { "very-unique": false };` - that key name could be overwritten by anyone using the key `very-unique`. However, using `var obj = { [Symbol.for("very-unique")]: true };` you can be guaranteed the key can only be accessed or overwritten by the value for that Symbol.

Answer (score 4):

That is not how `Symbol.for` works.

If you create a new `Symbol` using the `Symbol` function, you will get a unique symbol every time. Example:

```
const sym1 = Symbol("x");
const sym2 = Symbol("x");
sym1 === sym2; // returns false
```

If you want to use a global symbol, you will have to define it using [`Symbol.for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/for) as well:

```js
const sym = Symbol.for("x");    

let obj = {
  [sym]: "val"
}
    
console.log(obj[Symbol.for("x")]); // "val"
console.log(obj[sym]); // "val"
```

```js
const sym = Symbol("x");    

let obj = {
  [sym]: "val"
}
    
console.log(obj[Symbol("x")]); // undefined
console.log(obj[sym]); // "val"
```