# What advantage of using Symbol.for('string') instead the plain string

Tags: javascript, string, ecmascript-6, symbols

When I use a code like this:

```
const sym = Symbol('toAvoidInterference');
document.querySelector('#someid')[sym] = 'Hello, world!';
```

it makes sense to avoid interference with another attributes names. But what difference and benefit of using:

```
const sym = Symbol.for('attributeName');
document.querySelector('#someid')[sym] = 'Hello, world!';
```

if it is the same as we can write instead:

```
document.querySelector('#someid')['attributeName'] = 'Hello, world!';
```

In both cases, another developer may use an attribute of the same name despite it is wrapped into `for` method of `Symbol` or not because we can not be sure this string is unique. Why it is needed to use Symbol.for() instead of using plain string?

UPD.
I suddenly invented the most useful feature of `Symbol.for()` call. If there is using symbols in your code sometimes it is difficult to use *conditional breakpoints* while debugging. For example, you need to catch if the variable equals the value which is of symbol type and this value binded in the different module. The first difficult way is to use this value as a constant and export it from that module. In this case, the condition of the breakpoint will look:

```
catchedVariable === exportedSymbolConst
```

But the easiest way is to temporarily change the code inside the module adding `.for` to `Symbol`. Then you can write the condition:

```
catchedVariable === Symbol.for('string_key')
```

After the successful debugging you will be changing the code back just removing `.for` part.

Comment: You don't use `Symbol.for()` if you need unique symbols.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30984858/symbol-forstring-in-ecmascript-6

Comment: Exact duplicate of [What's the purpose of registry symbols (Symbol.for) in Javascript ES6?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49619054/1048572)

Comment: I am just learning about Javascript Symbols and am wondering exactly the same. First, inventing a way to define unique, non-clashing symbols and then immediately adding a global registry re-establishing clashing string-handles by defining `for()` is a really confusing concept, given that you can evade enumeration using `defineProperty()` anyway.

Answer (score 5):

You don't use `Symbol.for()` if you're trying to avoid conflicts with other code that uses a global symbol with the same name.

So why use a registered symbol instead of a string? Symbols have other features that strings don't have.

- `Object.keys()` and `Object.values()` won't return any properties named using symbols, you have to use `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols()`.
- They won't conflict with string keys; if you use symbols for properties on DOM elements, you don't have to worry about them conflicting with properties added in a future version of the DOM.
- They don't automatically coerce to primitive types, so they're good for catching errors.

There's some more information about what symbols are good for in [Metaprogramming in ES6: Symbols and why they're awesome](https://www.keithcirkel.co.uk/metaprogramming-in-es6-symbols/)

Comment: They're also not enumerable, that's another great benefit. I should clarify that statement. They're not enumerable via `for...in`, even though their property descriptor says that they're enumerable.

Comment: According to the page I linked to, you have to make them non-enumerable with `Object.defineProperty()`.