# Javascript Symbol.for() vs import and export normal Symbol() variable

Tags: javascript, symbols

> As we’ve seen, usually all symbols are different, even if they have
> the same names. But sometimes we want same-named symbols to be same
> entities.
>
> For instance, different parts of our application want to access symbol
> "id" meaning exactly the same property.
> [Source](https://javascript.info/symbol).

Why not just `export const mySymbol = Symbol("mySymbol");` instead? Then import it from anywhere in your application, making it pretty much a "global".

When is better to choose one over the other approach?

Comment: If you `delete require.cache[filename]` and then require it again, it would be different object

Comment: there is nothing in your linked article talking about exporting the symbol, these are unrelated concepts. your code is perfectly valid.

Comment: Yes, if you can use modules and simply share a symbol by them, that's the better solution. The [use case of `Symbol.for`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30985314/1048572) is when you cannot easily share a constant, but still need the same symbol.