# Symbol.for() JavaScript and iframes

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, symbols

The following code throws "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'undefined')" when it should show 123. What am I doing wrong? I asked a similar question here [Symbols and cross realms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71592844/symbols-and-cross-realms) but nobody answered my specific question about cross realms

```
<body>
  <iframe srcdoc="<script>var sym = Symbol(); var obj = {}; obj[sym] = 123;</script>">
  </iframe>
  <script>
    const iframe = document.querySelector('iframe');
    const content = iframe.contentWindow;
    const value = content.obj[content.sym]; // undefined
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: You'll need to wait until iframe has loaded -> `iframe.addEventListener('load', () => { do the thing here})`

Comment: Oh, thanks, so, if I do the same with my other link question it will now show the use of Symbol.for() right?

Comment: You need the iframe to be loaded to use it, so, what do you think?

Comment: Yea, thanks, it worked, what happened is that in the articles I read nobody used the "load" and as I had never used iframes I got confused, thank you very much, now I understand the use of Symbol.for() to cross realms.